# Objective-C - Replicating exit(0) and fixing EXC_BAD_ACCESS

Tags: objective-c, ios, opengl-es, exc-bad-access

Having some seriously frustrating issues with my latest app!!

I'm using OpenGLES 1 to draw models to the screen that are constantly updating, then you can take a screenshot and share however you like, after that you can return to the app start screen and start again.

All seems to work fine the first time the app runs through, no crashes. But if you run through it once then try to go through again, as soon as the OpenGLES drawing view has to start drawing the elements, it throws up an `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` error on my `glDrawElements` line.

I given up on trying to fix this error for now, I've had no luck in the last 2 weeks!!

I have set the property in my plist so that the app doesn't run in the background, and whenever I run it through once, then exit it and load it up again it will run through again absolutely fine.

So what I was wondering is if I could somehow emulate the functionality of the `exit(0)` feature, but without actually exiting from the app?

So in essence, each time the user navigates from the sharing page back to the home page, the app would run the `exit` code, leaving the app to run from scratch again.

This would, in my head at least, not be a great way at all of dealing with the situation, but I need results quick and this seems like a good way out for now until I can get to the bottom of the actual error.

Thanks,

Matt

EDIT 1: I'm not looking to put the app on the store with this fix in place, it is just a temporary thing.

EDIT 2: Posted code containing my draw functionality, taken and adapted from [Bill Dudney's WaveFront .obj loader](http://bill.dudney.net/roller/objc/entry/wave_front_obj_textures_working)

```
for(WaveFrontOBJGroup *group in scene.groups)
{
    NSString *matPath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@.mtl", materialName, modelPart];
    NSArray *materialArray = [WaveFrontOBJMaterial materialsFromLibraryFile:matPath];
    WaveFrontOBJMaterial *mat = [materialArray objectAtIndex:0];

    if(group.smoothing)
        glShadeModel(GL_SMOOTH);
    else
        glShadeModel(GL_FLAT);

    // load (if necessary) and bind the vertices
    GLuint verticesName = [group verticesName:GL_STATIC_DRAW];
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, verticesName);
    glVertexPointer(3, GL_FLOAT, 0, 0);

    // load (if necessary) and bind the normals
    GLuint normalsName = [group normalsName:GL_STATIC_DRAW];
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, normalsName);
    glNormalPointer(GL_FLOAT, 0, 0);

    ColorRGBA color = mat.ambientColor;
    glMaterialfv(GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL_AMBIENT, (GLfloat *)&color);
    color = mat.diffuseColor;
    if(alpha)
        glColor4f(color.red, color.green, color.blue, mat.disolve);
    else
        glColor4f(color.red, color.green, color.blue, color.alpha);
    glMaterialfv(GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL_DIFFUSE, (GLfloat *)&color);
    color = mat.specularColor;
    glMaterialfv(GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL_SPECULAR, (GLfloat *)&color);
    glMaterialf(GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL_SHININESS, mat.shine);

    // load (if necessary) and bind the texture
    if(group.textureCoordinatesIndexData.length > 0)
    {
        glEnableClientState(GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);
        GLuint textureCoordsName = [group textureCoordinatesName:GL_STATIC_DRAW];
        glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
        glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, textureCoordsName);
        glTexCoordPointer([group texCoordSize], GL_FLOAT, 0, 0);
        GLuint texId = [mat.diffuseTexture textureName];
        glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texId);
    }

    GLuint indexesName = [group indexesName:GL_STATIC_DRAW];
    glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, indexesName);

    glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, group.indexCount, GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT, NULL);
    //^^This line above is where I get the "EXC_BAD_ACCESS" message

    if(group.textureCoordinatesIndexData.length > 0)
        glDisableClientState(GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);
}
```

I've checked `group.indexCount` through breakpoints and NSLog's and it is not null, it is exactly the same as when it runs through the first time which works fine.

I realise it won't necessarily be on that line, I've heard other talk about it being due to variables not being initialised as pointers - `*` - or NSStrings not having matching identifiers and values `(@"%@ sometext %@", variable);` but I don't see any of those in my code, of course I could easily be missing one.

Comment: I'm thinking you should probably fix the error, and not use a hack like this that would get your rejected.

Comment: The app wouldn't be submitted to the store, it's for personal use only so thats nothing to worry about. Any other ideas?

Comment: What Richard said. It seems pretty likely that the place to look for your error is that you are not cleaning up properly after finishing your OpenGLES drawing and returning to the start screen.

Comment: To elaborate a bit, the thing that is likely fixing your bug when quitting the app is the OS is tearing things down for you. You can't "fake" this without actually letting the OS tear down the app or just cleaning up properly yourself.

Comment: Well could you help me try to clean up better? I've spent the last week and a half trying to find out whats going on, trying retaining things, looking in to NSZombies which I can't use cause the app will not compile on simulator, memory allocations and leaks in instruments. I've tried everything I can possibly think of and I know it's likely to be something simple, but I just can't think straight right now! :D Any help at all would be appreciated, even if just ideas of how else I could try to solve it, not even how to implement it! Matt

Answer (score 0):

Remember two things:

1) You have a method `-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated` in your home ViewController. This will call always (!) when user return to this screen (not like viewDidLoad).

2) If you even do this like you described you probably didn't get to the AppStore!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why your application won't compile on the simulator, but you should try to link your libraries appropriately so that you can get that up and running - nothing is better for bad access errors than zombies.

If you know your error is from calling `glDrawElements` then you should look into what's being passed to it. [This link](http://www.touch-code-magazine.com/how-to-debug-exc_bad_access/) might be able to help you.

The reason you can't get the "functionality" of exiting your app while still in the app is because it's not a function of the application - it's the OS throwing away everything associated with the application and then reloading it. By definition you won't be able to do this without actually shutting down.

However, if your problem is fixed by this, then it is likely that there's something in your setup that needs to be redone (initializations, declarations, etc). Check to see what's getting set to `nil` or thrown away and then set it back up.

Without looking at your code I can't say this with any certainty, but you may be able to write a method that overwrites/reinitializes all of your current variables. This would probably replicate the part of exiting the application that you need.

Comment: Thanks for your reply!My project won't compile on the simulator because it requires the camera (quite heavily, I simplified the explanation above to just the main parts involved in the issue)